# parallel for loop python

Tags: python, for-loop, parallel-processing, joblib

I would like to parallelize a for loop in python.

The loop gets fed by a generator and I expect 1 billion items.

It turned out, that joblib has a giant memory leak

```
Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(testtm)(tm) for tm in powerset(all_turns))
```

I do not want to store data in this loop, just print sometimes something out, but the main thread grows in seconds to 1 GB size.

Are there any other frameworks for a large number of iterations?

Comment: Running things in parallel doesn't magically fix memory leaks.

Comment: The memory leak is not in my code, at least I am pretty sure about that

Comment: Memoryleak seems to be in the joblib library, at least there is no leak without joblib anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == "__main__":
   pool = Pool() # use all available CPUs
   for result in pool.imap_unordered(delayed(testtm), powerset(all_turns),
                                     chunksize=1000):
       print(result)
```

Comment: btw: what is this __name__ line for?, results can be seen here: https://github.com/thigg/fapr/blob/master/graph/builder.py. Instead of Gigabytes of ram I need no ~10mb per task. Awesome!

Comment: `__main__` guard allows to import the module without creating a pool of processes. `multiprocessing` may import the module in the child processes.